# Jasper Report: lazy loading in subreport using hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jasper-reports

I have `Renderer` class that inside it's logic use hibernate in order to obtain data, eg:

```
result = getSession().load(getBeanClass(), id);
```

The weird thing is that `$P{renderer}.render($F{data}.get("ID"))` works fine when I use it inside main report and fails when I use it in subreport with following exception:

```
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression for source text: $P{renderer}.render($F{data}.get("ID"))
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:264)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:610)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:578)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElement.evaluateExpression(JRFillElement.java:1015)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluateText(JRFillTextField.java:572)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluate(JRFillTextField.java:556)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:258)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:454)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2029)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:755)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:262)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:122)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:551)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java:411)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:732)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:58)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.run(AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.java:216)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
```

I did debug and found out the place in `Spring 4.3.3` where it fails:

```
if(TransactionSynchronizationManager.isSynchronizationActive()) { // returns false here when renderer invoked from subreport
     //...
} else {
    throw new HibernateException("Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread");
}
```

**Question:**
Main question is how does invocation from MainReport  and invocation from SubReport change the situation with `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isSynchronizationActive()`? Do you have any idea how to fix this?